# Error when registering for Multiple Remote Notification Types

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, xcode4.2

XCode is driving me nuts, when I register for multiple notification types:

> ```
> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge];
> ```

or

> ```
> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];
> ```

It throws and error not a warning:

> error: Semantic Issue: Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'UIRemoteNotificationType' with an rvalue of type 'int'

Even though this is the same line that everyone uses (even Apple in their demos). I'm using the iOS 5 SDK (first one that came out after release of iOS 5) & XCode 4.2. The project is a older project (XCode 3 & iOS 4) that is being upgraded and targeted for iOS 5.

Comment: for all people reading this, this problem is solved in Xcode 4.3 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem too. The trick is if this code is in a .mm file (Objective C++), this error occurs. If you aren't using any C++ features, change the filename extension from .mm to .m and  it will compile OK.

Comment: Hi, thanks for figuring out the problem. I posted this a long time ago, but yes I do remember I was using Objective C++. So I will mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Try casting to `UIRemoteNotificationType`:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record I was never able to solve this problem completely. It is definitely a problem with the developer tools. The line in my UIApplicationDelegate didn't work. I was able to work around this by placing this line in my MainViewController rather than my ApplicationDelegate.

Answer (score -1):

put parentheses around the parameters like

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];
```

Comment: Nope thats not it, I had it like that before, and just tried it again, same error

Comment: i just compiled and ran a project with the exact line of code `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];` in Xcode 4.2 iOS 5.0

Comment: Yep, I did too, It's just not working in this project, its the strangest thing

Comment: um. thats weird. try a clean? no idea.

Comment: I did a clean, and a restart of XCode, still registering and error? Can I ignore the error with the compiler?